# round borders not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, slideshow, css

i am using a jquery slideshow, that works very nice. Only problem is, it doesnt show round borders on the images "div" in Google Chrome even though I specificly have used Chrome's CSS round border style. Because I know almost all browsers is using their own codes to have round borders, I have set all browsers available settings. But still, it does not work on Chrome like it should.

Instead of filling this tiny page with HTML and CSS I'd rather give you the [url](http://www.5eren.dk/scripts/jqueryslideshow/test.php) to the slideshow and you can read source code if you want to, CSS link is in `head` tag.

Comment: well the border radius works on your image "div" except it is much bigger than the images themselves so you don't see it since everything is white. See the answers to add border-radius to the img tag itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the **CSS to your Images** instead of the  `.slides_container`

Add this to your **CSS**

```
  img
    {
       -moz-border-radius: 10px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
       border-radius: 10px; 
    }
```

Comment: As a good and robuster practice, always put standard rules after their vendor-prefixed equivalent ;-) so that standard ones take precedence

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in your **CSS**

```
div.slides_control a img {border-radius: 12px;}
```

Comment: I don't think !important is needed

Answer (score 2):

Your example does have round corners, one can see them during transitions. But the containing `<a>`'s are wider than the images... Make the `<a>`'s the same size as the images, or better and simpler, apply the `border-radius` to the `<img>`'s.

Also, Firefox and Chrome have removed support for their vendor-prefixed `-moz-border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius`. Just use [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-radius#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#slides_control img {
   border-radius: 3px;
}
```

You don't need any browser prefixes: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Comment: it doesnt :/ ... i will answer my own question with the solution that works for ALL BROWSERS .. but thank you all very much for trying to help ..i really appreciate it .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for trying to help me.

It seems that there is some Google Chrome bug that prevents the overflow being hidden because the border command is working fine if you just want to style a div.

The solution is adding this to your style:

```
#slider{
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
}
```

Hopefully now other poor guys like myself won't spend all night up looking for a little bit piece of code that can save the day.